# Self-hosted SOAP Service C#.Net

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have an application which should host a service. The service is implementing an `Interface` likes this:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRegistrationCaseFetcherService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool CancelTransaction(string transactionControlNumber);

        [OperationContract]
        bool ConfirmTransaction(string transactionControlNumber);

        [OperationContract]
        bool UpdateTransaction(string transactionControlNumber, UpdatedRegistrationCase personData);

        [OperationContract]
        bool checkEndPoint();
    }
```

My Service is defined like this:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
    public class RegistrationCaseFetcherService : IRegistrationCaseFetcherService
    {
        static int CallsInProgress = 0;

        public bool CancelTransaction(string transactionControlNumber)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool ConfirmTransaction(string transactionControlNumber)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool UpdateTransaction(string transactionControlNumber, UpdatedRegistrationCase personData)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool checkEndPoint()
        {
            return true;
        }


        public static bool IsInUse
        {
            get
            {
                return (CallsInProgress != 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I do also have a class to trigger this service:

```
  public static class Services
  {
            private static ServiceHost _service;
            private static bool _isHosted = false;

            public static bool StartRecieveService()
            {
                var address = string.Format("http://{0}:8732/Services/RService", Dns.GetHostName());

                _service = new ServiceHost(typeof(RegistrationCaseFetcherService), new Uri(address));
                _service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRegistrationCaseFetcherService), new BasicHttpBinding(), address);

                var serviceMetaDataBehaviour = _service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (serviceMetaDataBehaviour == null) serviceMetaDataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                serviceMetaDataBehaviour.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                serviceMetaDataBehaviour.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

                _service.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetaDataBehaviour);

                try
                {
                    _service.Open();
                    _isHosted = true;
                    if (_service.BaseAddresses.Count > 0)
                        _logger.Trace(String.Format("Waiting for incomming calls on: {0}", _service.BaseAddresses[0].AbsoluteUri));
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.Error("Failed with exception: " + e);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

It seems that the service is being triggered when I debug, no exceptions are thrown. By opening the URL in my Web browser doesn't work, it says that the resource do not exist somehow. I also tried opening it in the `WCF Test Client`, but then I do get `Error: Cannot Obtain Metadata`.

How is it possible for me to actually verify that my service is up and running? And what changes in my code should I do to get it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us your Web.config

Comment: My web.config do not contain anything related to this. Should it? I want to make everything from the code. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: i just wanted to check the configuration of your webservice. In my opinion you are missing some tag or attribute required to run self hosted service.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3def9d4f-ae3e-468b-90e6-3a069bac6376/when-to-use-wcf-mex-endpoint

You will need to add at least one endpoint (here http for "wsdl"), where metadata is exposed:

```
_service.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
    "mex");
```